# If $f$ is a periodic function with period $L$, show that the integral $\int_{a}^{a+L}f(x)dx$ is independent of a.

Tags: integration

If $f$ is a periodic function with period $L$, show that the integral $\int_{a}^{a+L}f(x)dx$ is independent of a.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Show the integral over $[a,a+L]$ is the same as over $[a+nL,a+(n+1)L]$ for any $n$. Then choose $n$ so that $0\le a+nL < L$ and show that the integral over $[0,a+nL]$ is the same as over $[L,a+(n+1)L]$ and so the integral over $[a+nL,a+(n+1)L]$ is the same as $[0,L]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(a)=\int_{a}^{a+L} f(x) dx \implies I'(a)=f(a+L)= f(a)=0$$
Here we have used Leibnitz Rule for the differentiation of the integral w.r.t the limit variable. Next we have used the periodicity: $f(a+L)=f(a) ~~\forall a \in R$. Finally $I'(a)=0$ means that the integral does not depend on $a$.